# Helicon Redirect to IIS6 Virtual Directory - .htaccess Syntax and location

Tags: .htaccess, iis-6, isapi-rewrite

I'm moving my blog which was in a physical folder (/blog/) on my IIS 6 web server to a virtual directory called the same name (blog) running BlogEngine.net, the virtual directory is running in the same application pool as the parent website.

I want to redirect each .html post to the new BlogEngine.net URL. e.g.

> http://www.mywebsite.co.uk/blog/2009/06/old-blog-title.html
>   **to** 
>   http://www.mywebsite.co.uk/blog/post/new-blog-title.aspx

I already have Helicon ISAPI Rewrite Version 3.1.0.58 running on my website and currently have redirects working fine.  But redirects to the blog virtual directory don't seem to work.

**Current .htaccess rule:**

```
#rewriterule ^blog/2009/06/old-blog-title.html$ /blog/post/new-blog-title.aspx [R=301,L]
```

**Question 1:** Should I add the .htaccess rules to the blog Virual Directory root or the main website root?

**Question 2:** What .htaccess syntax should I be using to redirect to the virtual directory?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't get any response, but managed to figure it out myself. Is there a StackOverflow badge for that LOL :-)
I'm answering my own question just incase anyone else has the same problem.

**Answer to Question 1**

The .htaccess file should be located in the virtual directory root, but you can't edit this in the Helicon Rewrite tab of IIS 6 for the virtual directory as it wants to save the .htaccess file in a physical directory called /blog/ rather than the virtual directory.

**Answer to Question 2**

The rewrite needed to be amended slightly due to the .htaccess file location within the virtual directory. Basically removing blog/ from the beginning of the old url.

```
rewriterule ^2009/06/old-blog-title.html$ /blog/post/new-blog-title.aspx [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your rule is OK if you need to redirect just a couple of blog articles, but if you'll have hundreds of them, you'd better have a look at mapfiles functionality of ISAPI_Rewrite [here](http://www.helicontech.com/forum/forum_posts-TID-10648.htm).

> but you can't edit this in the Helicon Rewrite tab of IIS 6 for the virtual directory

This problem was fixed in build 62, so update and enjoy.

Comment: Unfortunately the old URLs don't follow a consistent structure where I can apply a rule to them :-(

Thanks for the heads-up on the Helicon Rewrite fix though!